# Multithread Singeleton Substitution with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, mstest, nsubstitute

I have a public method ValidateWords inside FooService.To test the ValidateWord method, I created IAppSettingWrapper and AppSettingWrapper which returns the Instance of AppSettings.

Inside the test method, I want to substitute NotAllowedWords using NSubstitute. However, it throws an object reference exception. Is there any way for substitution? If it's not possible, how can I refactor my static instance?

```
public sealed class AppSettings
{
    private static object _lockObject = new object();
    private static volatile AppSettings? _instance;
    private static DateTime _cacheTime;
    private Settings[] _settings;

    public AppSettings()
    {
        try
        {

            _settings = GetSettings();
        }
        catch { }
    }
    public static AppSettings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new AppSettings();
                }

            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    public List<string> NotAllowedWords
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string>() { 
                  "index",
                  "change"
            };
        }
    }

    public T GetValues<T>(string key,T defaultValue)
    {
        T result = defaultValue;
        var settings = _settings.Where(i => i.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
        result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(settings.Value, typeof(T));
        return result;
    }
    private Settings[]? GetSettings()
    {
        //gets data from web services
        return base.Channel.GetSettings();
    }
}
public class Settings
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IAppSettingsWrapper
{
    public AppSettings Instance();
}

public class AppSettingsWrapper : IAppSettingsWrapper
{
    public AppSettings Instance()
    {
        return AppSettings.Instance;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class FooServiceTest{
    private IAppSettingsWrapper _appSettingsWrapper;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize(IAppSettingsWrapper appSettingsWrapper)
    {
        _appSettingsWrapper = Substitute.For<IAppSettingsWrapper>();
    }
    private FooService CreateFooService()
    {
        return new FooService(_appSettingsWrapper);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Throw_Exception_When_Given_Word_Not_Allowed() {
        var service = this.CreateFooService();
        _appSettingsWrapper.Instance().NotAllowedWords.Returns(new List<string> { "index" });
        var word = "index";
        Exception ex = Assert.ThrowsException<Exception>(() => service.ValidateWords(word));
        Assert.AreEqual("this word is not allowed", ex.Message);
    }
}

public class FooService
{
    private IAppSettingsWrapper _appSettingsWrapper;
    public FooService(IAppSettingsWrapper appSettingsWrapper)
    {
        _appSettingsWrapper = appSettingsWrapper;
    }


    public void ValidateWords(string word)
    {
        if (_appSettingsWrapper.Instance().NotAllowedWords.Contains(word))
        {
            throw new Exception("this word is not allowed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `AppSettings.NotAllowedWords` property is not substitutable due to it not being virtual and the class being sealed. If you add [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to your test project it will help you find these cases. (The [How NSubstitute Works](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/how-nsub-works/) documentation outlines why this is the case.)

One option is to make `AppSettings` implement an `IAppSettings` interface and inject that into `FooService` (rather than the wrapper). Then you can use a substitute for tests, and `AppSettings.Instance` for your real code.